# Creating a Server Control for <input type="email">

Tags: asp.net, controls, server

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  (I have Visual Studio 2013, but I just find it's too hard to use)....So I don't have any of the new `HTML5` controls in my environment.

I would like to create a custom Server Control that would produce this output:

```
<input type="email">
```

I have created this class:

```
public class TextBoxEmail : System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText
    {
        protected override void RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteAttribute("type", "email");
            base.Attributes.Remove("type");

            base.RenderAttributes(writer);
        }

    }
```

But the problem is that this produces this output:

```
<input type="email" type="text">
```

My Question is:
How do I get rid of the extra `type="text`?

Actually, I would prefer to inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` INSTEAD of `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText`, but I have no clue how to do that.

I have viewstate disabled for the whole website so I do not use that at all... I never use it.

I know I could probably inherit from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl`, which takes "type" as a parameter in it's constructor, but I could not figure out how to do it.  Besides, I need all of the functionality inside `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText`, that prepopulates the textbox on PostBack.... I have tried to figure all that out and cannot do it.  If I could, I would just build this control from scratch.

There's not a lot of info out there about creating Server Controls.  It's as if this Server-Control-making-thing never really took off that much.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case I would not recommend you to create a server control you could use the normal `TextBox` and modify the type attribute.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMail"/>
```

And the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtMail.Attributes["type"] = "email";
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your code, but it produces this in the HTML:  <input type="email" type="text"  name="txtMail" >.... How do I get rid of the extra "type" attribute?  Thanks

Comment: Wich version of asp.net are you using? for me it render as ```<input name="txtMail" id="txtMail" type="email">``` check if you're use the common asp:Textbox and the code is in the Page_Load function without conditionals for the IsPostBack